# Import data from txt file to mysql workbench - windows

Tags: mysql, file, security, import, mysql-workbench

I have a kind of huge amount of data on a .txt file (something like 90.000 lines and 10 columns, each 'item' separed by comma) and I need to find a way to import it from my txt file to a mysql table. 
I did some research and found the following code:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "/my_path/file.txt" INTO TABLE "table" CHARACTER SET "utf8" FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," LINES TERMINATED BY "\r\n";
```

but that gives me the following error:

```
Error Code: 29. File '/my_path/file.txt' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)    0.000 sec
```

So after searching a little bit more, I found that a lot of people had this issue but solved just by putting the word 'LOCAL' (LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE), but that gives me this error:

```
Error Code: 1148. The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version   0.000 sec
```

(I'm using MySQL Workbench 8.0)

So I tried to set some global variables like `secure-file-priv=""`, `loose-local-infile=1` and `local-infile=1` in my my.ini file, but nothing seems to work.

Can anyone help me please...

**Ps 1**: I can't use the wizard import because even though it would work, it's too slow

**Ps 2**: I tried to convert my txt file to csv but it didn't work either.

Comment: Three dots `/.../.../` don't have a meaning in a path. One dot `/././` means the current directory, and two dots `/../../` mean the parent directory. But three dots?  Nothing useful.

Comment: @O.Jones That was my bad, when I wrote the three dots I was trying to mean my path. Already edited it. Thanks

Comment: Why do you have a slash on the end of the path? Surely, as it is a file you want accessed, the path should end with myfile.txt or whatever?

Comment: @MandyShaw It was just a way to represent that that was the place where my path goes, sorry if I didn't represent it correctly (didn't want to put the whole path here), but I fixed that, thanks for your comment

Comment: Does the account under which mysql is running have access to your file?

Comment: @MandyShaw I'm kinda new to sql so I don't have an answer to your question, where can I check this?

Comment: Might be easier to try moving your file to somewhere on the PC that isn't likely to have permissions issues (i.e., if your file is in the c:\users\username hierarchy, maybe try moving it into the root directory or into c:\temp). (You can tell what user mysql is running under in various ways, but the easiest is probably to find the service (via control panel) and look at its definition.)

Comment: @MandyShaw Just tried that and it gave the same error (error code: 29 file not found, permission denied). Here's the path that I put the file into: C:\Users\lucas\AppData\Local\Temp\file.txt

Comment: @MandyShaw I also tried to put in the root (C:\myfile.txt) and ti gave me a different error (Error Code: 1300. Invalid utf8 character string: '' 0.047 sec)

Comment: That sounds as if it's reading the file now.

Comment: I should make sure you've got the file saved with the correct character set.

Comment: @MandyShaw yeah, I know that my file uses the ANSI character set (it needs to be this set), so how would I change the LOAD DATA INFILE code to import from this character set?

Comment: You've got CHARACTER SET "utf8" on your SQL statement, suggest you google a bit (I don't know off the top of my head, sorry). Maybe go back to whoever gave you the SQL. Or just take that clause out and try without.

Comment: @MandyShaw I've been searching but I couldn't get anything to work... I trie to change the CHARACTER SET line, tried to change the character set of my table in my db, but nothing works

Comment: Hopefully someone else will come along who can help out. Or go back to whoever gave you the SQL.

Comment: You basically need the data, the file's saved-as character set, and the character set clause in the SQL all to match.

Comment: @MandyShaw Well, I'll keep trying to get the answer, thanks for all your help anyways...

Comment: There are quite a lot of questions on StackOverflow re LOAD DATA INFILE + character sets, I should have a look at some of those if you have not done so already.

Comment: @MandyShaw I tried with every single character set, but most of them just returns this: `0 row(s) affected Records: 0  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0`. So my guess is that is not even reading the file correctly

Comment: @MandyShaw Just a ps, I got it working (using this code: `LOAD DATA INFILE C:\\option_data.txt INTO TABLE option_data CHARACTER SET utf8 FIELDS TERMINATED BY , LINES TERMINATED BY \r\n IGNORE 1 LINES (@col2,@col3,@col4,@col5,@col6,@col7,@col8) set time_id=cast(@col2 as unsigned integer),option_id=cast(@col3 as unsigned integer), a=@col4,b=@col5,c=@col6,d=@col7,e=@col8;`) but I had to manually convert my file to utf8 encode, but in my case I can't every time that I will import the data convert the encode page manually...

Comment: Delighted to hear it's now working. If you can't get it working with their provided encoding I suggest you ask the originator of the file to change the encoding they ship it to you with. In the meantime I will now build a formal answer based on where we've got to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP had 2 problems:

a) mysql did not have access to the input file from a permissions perspective

b) the input file was not correctly encoded.

Once the access issue was resolved and the input file encoding had been corrected to utf8, the load worked correctly.

Comment: Thanks for all the help you provided, I'll try to build a simple c# application to do all this encode conversion so I don't have to do it manually... Thanks again for all your help

Answer (score 2):

[Without `LOCAL`, `LOAD DATA INFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) tells the MySQL server to find the file on the file system *of its own machine* and read it.

So, the path and file have to exist on the server machine. And, the credentials (the username) under which the MySQL server runs must have read access to the file.

Your `permission denied` error hints to me that the MySQL server can't read the file.

Comment: Hey @O. Jones, thanks for your reply, when you say the the path and file have to exist on the server machine, you mean just that my server (in my case, local) and the file have to be (e.g.) in the same computer? Just to make myself clear, both the file and the server are on the same computer